# Continue a code after calling a class method which opens a tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a class "Node" which creates a binary tree. (I know i can use binarytree module but its a project given to me in DSA subject.)

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data) -> None:
        #initialisation

    def addNode(self, data): 
        # Code to add data.
        

    def traverse(self):
        #traverses the tree and returns a dict

    def view(
        self,
        length=500,
        width=1000,
        yDist=50,
        xDistScale=0.25,
        title='Tree View',
    ):
        # shows the tree in a tkinter window as in the screenshot attached
        tree = self.traverse()
        root = tk.Tk()
        self.root=root
        root.geometry(str(width)+'x'+str(length))
        root.title(title)

        # ........ some code which places the nodes on the window using the place() method

        root.mainloop()
```

Now, I import the code in an another file, create an instance of the class add some nodes and call the view() method it works fine but the code after the view() methd does not run till I close the tkinter window.
How can I make the code after view() run without the window being closed?
Its ok if the window is not able to update.

Code where I import and use the node class :

```
t1 = Node(15)
t1.addNode(12)
t1.addNode(27)
t1.addNode(7)
t1.addNode(14)
t1.addNode(20)
t1.addNode(88)
t1.addNode(23)

t1.view()

# The code here does not run until I close the window.
```

Output of the above code :
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYIMi.png)

I tried googling and also viewed following stackoverflow posts:

- [Calling a tkinter application from a different class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088462/a-code-needs-to-be-continued-python-with-tkinter),
- [A code needs to be continued...(Python with Tkinter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088462/a-code-needs-to-be-continued-python-with-tkinter)
- [How would I continue to run code after importing a Tkinter file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65730288/how-would-i-continue-to-run-code-after-importing-a-tkinter-file)
- Few other websites and guides...

But nothing was helpful.
Please help/guide me.
I am new to StackOverflow and Python.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1: Don't update window**
You could replace the `root.mainloop()` with `root.update()`. This will stop showing any changes to the window. The window will only and always close if the program stops running.


**Method 2: using threading**
You could use`import threading` to run `t1.view()` in another thread:  `threading.Thread(target=t1.view).start()`. This may result in a Tcl_AsyncDelete error.